# Is there any way to prevent flutter sending crash reports to Google

Tags: flutter

I use flutter command-line tools. Every time I close the app then stop `flutter run` using Ctrl+C, Flutter appears to send a crash report to Google :

> Sending crash report to Google.

I already ran `flutter config --no-analytics`, when I run `flutter config` I have this line :

> Analytics reporting is currently disabled.

There is already an open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19304) on GitHub but it has no pertinent answers yet.

Do you have any idea? I don't mind sending anonymous reports if I have a real issue, but this is a simple Ctrl+C.

Comment: so you try to stop `flutter run` command by pressing `Ctrl-C`? do i understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, do you think it's related to this? Should I use `d` and `q` instead?

Comment: i always use `q` - btw does `d` (i mean detach) work at you? are you able to attach after detaching? for me it does not work: attaching waits forever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick :

```
flutter run --suppress-analytics
```